# Why is my inet for ip colored red?

Tags: server, webserver, ip, ip-address

I'm trying to set up a web server but when I try to see the ip of the server with this code `ifconfig | grep inet` the four `inet` that comes up is colored red and shows some numbers. If I continue another message comes up and tells me that there is nothing wrong with my ip.

What is wrong and what can I do?

Comment: Screenshot? Your question is hard to understand.

Comment: Please explain what you are attempting to do. `ifconfig | grep inet` does not set anything up, it will simply show you information (such as the IP, which _is_ a string of numbers) about your current setup.

Answer (score 3):

Red is the default color for matches when using `grep` with the  `--color=auto` option (which is set by your default `~/.bashrc` file).

It has no significance beyond indicating that `grep` found the text that you asked it to search for.